# Java GUI Adding objects to database

Tags: java, swing

So I made a GUI which in this case if you want to add a Car to the database, you click "Add"
then a JFrame pops out with the following code:

```
  public void newCar()
   {


      JFrame window = new JFrame("New Car");

      JPanel newCarButtons = new JPanel();

      newCarButtons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      saveCar=new JButton("Save");
      saveCar.addActionListener(buttonListener);
      newCarButtons.add(saveCar);

      cancelCar=new JButton("Cancel");
      cancelCar.addActionListener(buttonListener);
      newCarButtons.add(cancelCar);



      JPanel newCarText = new JPanel();

      GroupLayout group = new GroupLayout(newCarText);

      newCarText.setLayout(group);

      group.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
      group.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

      JLabel make = new JLabel("Brand:");
      JTextField maket = new JTextField(10);

      newCarText.add(make);
      newCarText.add(maket);

      JLabel model = new JLabel("Model:");
      JTextField modelt = new JTextField(10);

      newCarText.add(model);
      newCarText.add(modelt);

      JLabel license = new JLabel("License Plate Numbers:");
      JTextField licenset = new JTextField(10);

      newCarText.add(license);
      newCarText.add(licenset);

      JLabel color = new JLabel("Color:");
      JTextField colort = new JTextField(10);

      newCarText.add(color);
      newCarText.add(colort);

      JLabel year = new JLabel("Year:");
      final JTextField yeart = new JTextField(10);
      yeart.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
      {
         @Override
         public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
         {
            super.keyTyped(e);

            e.getKeyCode();

            if (!((int) e.getKeyChar() >= 48 && (int) e.getKeyChar() <= 57))
            {
               e.consume();
            }
         }

      });

      newCarText.add(year);
      newCarText.add(yeart);

      JLabel horse = new JLabel("Horse Power: ");
      JTextField horset = new JTextField(10);

      newCarText.add(horse);
      newCarText.add(horset);

      JLabel isAvailable = new JLabel("Car Status:");
      JLabel isAvailablet = new JLabel("Available");

      newCarText.add(isAvailable);
      newCarText.add(isAvailablet);

      JLabel time = new JLabel("Time Until Service: ");
      JTextField timet = new JTextField(10);

      newCarText.add(time);
      newCarText.add(timet);

      JLabel consumption = new JLabel("Consumption per 100km: ");
      JTextField consumptiont = new JTextField(10);

      newCarText.add(consumption);
      newCarText.add(consumptiont);



      JLabel seats = new JLabel("Number of Seats: ");
      JTextField seatst = new JTextField(10);
      seatst.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
      {
         @Override
         public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
         {
            super.keyTyped(e);

            e.getKeyCode();

            if (!((int) e.getKeyChar() >= 48 && (int) e.getKeyChar() <= 57))
            {
               e.consume();
            }
         }

      });

      newCarText.add(seats);
      newCarText.add(seatst);

      JLabel doors = new JLabel("Number of Doors: ");
      JTextField doorst = new JTextField(10);

      doorst.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
      {
         @Override
         public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
         {
            super.keyTyped(e);

            e.getKeyCode();

            if (!((int) e.getKeyChar() >= 48 && (int) e.getKeyChar() <= 57))
            {
               e.consume();
            }
         }

      });

      newCarText.add(doors);
      newCarText.add(doorst);

      JLabel transmission = new JLabel("Transmission ");
      JComboBox transmissiont = new JComboBox<String>();

      transmissiont.addItem("Auto");
      transmissiont.addItem("Manual");

      transmissiont.addActionListener(buttonListener);

      newCarText.add(transmission);
      newCarText.add(transmissiont);

      JLabel climate = new JLabel("Climate Control: ");
      JComboBox climatet = new JComboBox<String>();
      climatet.addItem("Yes");
      climatet.addItem("No");

      newCarText.add(climate);
      newCarText.add(climatet);

      GroupLayout.SequentialGroup hGroup = group.createSequentialGroup();

      hGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup().addComponent(make)
            .addComponent(model).addComponent(license).addComponent(color)
            .addComponent(time).addComponent(consumption)
            .addComponent(year).addComponent(horse).addComponent(isAvailable)
            .addComponent(seats).addComponent(doors).addComponent(transmission)
            .addComponent(climate));

      hGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup().addComponent(maket)
            .addComponent(modelt).addComponent(licenset).addComponent(colort)
            .addComponent(timet).addComponent(consumptiont)
            .addComponent(yeart).addComponent(isAvailablet)
            .addComponent(horset).addComponent(seatst).addComponent(doorst)
            .addComponent(transmissiont).addComponent(climatet));

      group.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);

      GroupLayout.SequentialGroup vGroup = group.createSequentialGroup();

      vGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(make).addComponent(maket));
      vGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(model).addComponent(modelt));
      vGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(license).addComponent(licenset));
      vGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(color).addComponent(colort));
      vGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(year).addComponent(yeart));
      vGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(horse).addComponent(horset));
      vGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(time).addComponent(timet));
      vGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(consumption).addComponent(consumptiont));
      vGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(isAvailable).addComponent(isAvailablet));
      vGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(seats).addComponent(seatst));
      vGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(doors).addComponent(doorst));
      vGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(transmission).addComponent(transmissiont));
      vGroup.addGroup(group.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(climate).addComponent(climatet));

      group.setVerticalGroup(vGroup);

      JPanel newCar = new JPanel();
      newCar.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      newCar.add(newCarText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      newCar.add(newCarButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      newCar.setBorder(new TitledBorder(BorderFactory
            .createLineBorder(Color.black), "[New Car]", 2, 0));

      Car car1= new Car(maket.getText(), modelt.getText(), licenset.getText(), colort.getText(), Integer.parseInt("yeart.getText()"), null, horset.getText(), timet.getText(), consumptiont.getText(), Integer.parseInt("seatst.getText()"), Integer.parseInt("doorst.getText()"), null,  null, 0);

      window.add(newCar);
      window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      window.setSize(400, 450);
      window.setVisible(true);

   }
```

Notice that at the bottom there is a Car object. This is where i need your help. The adapter, when adding cars, takes a Car object as an argument, so the idea is to fill out all the text fields and based on the text you input , you create a new Car object. But if I do this ,this way it will just create a empty Car object since when you open the window you don't have anything in the textfields. So how do i make that when you click "Add" it sends out a filled Car object based on the content in the text fields?

Button Listener:

```
private class MyButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         if (e.getSource() == addCars)
         {
            newCar();

         }

         if (e.getSource() == saveCar)
         {

            adapter.addCar(car);
         }
       }
   }
```

Comment: What this _this_ mean "_when you click "Add" it sends out a filled Car object_"? I Really don't get what your problem is.

Comment: my problem is that i don't know how to send a car object ,which has all the argument it needs taken out from the textfields in the JPanel, to the database.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: what does that have to do with anything? phpMyAdmin (MySQL)

Comment: I don't see any database code and your question asks about a database

Comment: `adapter.addCar(car);` this is where I call the method from the adapter to add the car ,it's pretty clear ,i don't know which part are you looking at the screen, next time check the code before you comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply pass your `car` object as argument to `newCar` method and initialize proper fields there just as you are doing when you are persisting car instance?

```
 if (e.getSource() == addCars)
 {
    newCar(car);

 }
```

remember to change `newCar` method signature.

```
  public void newCar(Car newCar)
   {
     //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH THAT DATA AND INITIALIZE PROPER FIELDS

      JFrame window = new JFrame("New Car");
    (.....)
```

Comment: but what about `if (e.getSource() == saveCar)
         {
          
            adapter.addCar(car);
         }` 
I need that ,after the "Add" button click , it would sent a queries to the database with that object. But i need the object fields to be filled out in the newCar panel.

Comment: Wrap it in proper logic. You are a programmer after all right?

Comment: Does your JFrame "see" the database or is there another object you have that handles database transactions? You want to validate your car entry when the "Add" button is pressed, then pass the car to the object that can actually "see" the database, and then have that class validate the car is okay, then have that class insert into the database. Or you can do it from the JFrame if you enjoy passing around database connections.

Answer (score 0):

This should go inside the listener

```
Car car1= new Car(maket.getText(), modelt.getText(), licenset.getText(), 
                 colort.getText(), Integer.parseInt("yeart.getText()"), null,
                 horset.getText(), timet.getText(), consumptiont.getText(), 
                 Integer.parseInt("seatst.getText()"),  
                 Integer.parseInt("doorst.getText()"), 
                 null,  null, 0);
```

You want to get the text when the button is pressed. Not in your constructor

```
 private class MyButtonListener implements ActionListener
 {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
         if (e.getSource() == addCars)
         {
             newCar();  // I don't know what you're trying to do here
         }

         if (e.getSource() == saveCar)
         {
             Car car1= new Car(maket.getText(), modelt.getText(), licenset.getText(), 
                     colort.getText(), Integer.parseInt("yeart.getText()"), null,
                     horset.getText(), timet.getText(), consumptiont.getText(), 
                     Integer.parseInt("seatst.getText()"),  
                     Integer.parseInt("doorst.getText()"), 
                     null,  null, 0);

             // add car1 to database
         }
     }
 }
```

**Edit:** Declare all your textfields as class members, then you can use them in yout listener class

```
public class GUI{
    JTextFeild maket = new JTextField();
    JTextFeild licenset = new JTextField();
    JTextFeild colort = new JTextField();
    JTextFeild yeart = new JTextField();
    JTextFeild horset = new JTextField();
    JTextFeild timet = new JTextField();
    JTextFeild consumptiont = new JTextField();
    JTextFeild maket = new JTextField();

    public void newCar(){
        ...  // remove your textfields from here.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ...
    }

    private class MyButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getSource() == addCars)
            {
                newCar();  // I don't know what you're trying to do here
            }

            if (e.getSource() == saveCar)
            {
                Car car1= new Car(maket.getText(), modelt.getText(), licenset.getText(), 
                    colort.getText(), Integer.parseInt("yeart.getText()"), null,
                    horset.getText(), timet.getText(), consumptiont.getText(), 
                    Integer.parseInt("seatst.getText()"),  
                    Integer.parseInt("doorst.getText()"), 
                    null,  null, 0);

                // add car1 to database
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Tried this already, I get error because it doesn't recognize the fields `maket cannot be resolved`

Comment: Make sure you declare all your textfield as class members and not in the constructor

Comment: what do you mean class member?

Comment: Look at my answer. If you delcare them in the constructor, they cant be used by the listener class. But if they are declared globally (class members), they they _can_ be used by the listener class.

Comment: What is your Class name? Is it `newCar`?

Comment: I have a Class called GUI inside it there's the main panel and all the buttons, as well as this method.

Comment: Then you should declare all the TextFields as memebers of the GUI class. forget the `public class newCar`. I thought newCar was your class

Comment: It's ok,but how do i declare them members of GUI class?

Comment: See my edit. Make sure you remove them from inside your newCar() method. You can leave everything else the same.

Comment: this is what i get  when i put the labels and textfields outside of the method. `Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "public", new 
  expected
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
  construct(s)
 - newCar cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: for now no errors ,but how do i call the window now? previously i just had to call the method.

Comment: You can still do it. I don't know what you did, but you only had to make the textfields class members, not eveything else. Everythin else should've stayed the same.

Comment: tried to add something , but i just get null pointer exceptions.

Comment: If your code ran before (window showed), all you needed to do was make the textfeilds global and and the car code to the listener, add everyhing should still work the same. You should also delete the car code you orinigally had in the method. The one I told you to move to the listener

Comment: I did what you told me to do and i got the Syntax error which i previously wrote. `Multiple markers at this line
 - newCar cannot be resolved to a 
  type
 - Syntax error on token "void", @ 
  expected`

Comment: Another thing. You can't parse this `Integer.parseInt("doorst.getText()")`. Remove the quotes

Comment: Oh, and the three things wrong with my code above. 1) Misspelling of JTextFiled 2) public newCar should be how you had it `public void newCar` 3) I added `JTextField maket` twice (You should make sure just to add all YOUR text fields. Other than that, I get no syntax errors

Comment: So this is what i did i took all of the labels and fields that i had and put them before the whole GUI class   `private JButton addBookings;
   private JButton removeBookings;` and so on and i left everything as it was in the beginning, no i just get nullpointer exceptions

Comment: And the nullpointerexception, I don't know, It maybe that you're trying to pass null values. Why are you even trying to do that? Makes no sense. Why don't you just delete those parameters from your `Car` constructor if you're just going to pass null to them.

Comment: So is the program running, but you just get null pointer exception when you're trying to add?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's happening, and i can't delete the fields because the Car constructor takes arguments, if i delete them it will just make errors

Comment: I meant can't you just delete them from the cunstructor? Since you're not passing anything to it. All your passing is null, so why even have those arguments in the constructor at all?

Comment: I'm going to pass them eventually, but first i need to test the adding part.

Comment: Just pass something besides null to see if that solve the nullpointeexception, some random value

Comment: `Car car1 = new Car("something", "something",
                  "something", "something",
                  15, "something","something",
                  "something", "something", 2, 2, "something",
                  "something", 2);
adapter.addCar(car1);`  Still get null pointer exception,but now its on the adapter line

Comment: What exactly is adapter?

Comment: can't post it, too large